# Problema con variable razor mvc

Tags: .net, mvc, razor

tengo una clas EsperRule la cual tiene algunas propiedades, entre ellas otra EsperRule, mi objetivo es mostrar todos los datos de la EsperRule y en caso de que la otra EsperRule sea distinto de null, muestre los datos de esa y así sucesivamente.

Hice algo así pero no me funciona:

```
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
            <table class="table" style="margin-bottom:0px">
                <tr><td><label>Campo</label></td><td>@Model.Field</td></tr>
                <tr><td><label>Operador lógico</label></td><td>@Model.LogicalOperator</td></tr>
                <tr><td><label>Umbral</label></td><td>@Model.Threshold</td></tr>
                <tr><td><label>Operador de unión</label></td><td>@Model.MergeOperator</td></tr>
            </table>
            @{EsperRule next = @Model.NextEsperRule; }
            @while (next != null)
            {
                <table class="table" style="margin-bottom:0px">
                    <tr><td><label>Campo</label></td><td>@next.Field</td></tr>
                    <tr><td><label>Operador lógico</label></td><td>@next.LogicalOperator</td></tr>
                    <tr><td><label>Umbral</label></td><td>@next.Threshold</td></tr>
                    <tr><td><label>Operador de unión</label></td><td>@next.MergeOperator</td></tr>
                </table>
                @next = @next.NextEsperRule;
            }
        </div>
```

Me tira error en: `@next = @next.NextEsperRule;`
Como podría solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente elimina las @ ya que estas dentro de un codigo de un bloque de instrucciones:

```
 @while (next != null)
{
    <table class="table" style="margin-bottom:0px">
                   //..
        </table>


   next = next.NextEsperRule; //eliminado las arrobas
 }
```

Comment: Hermano disculpa. Acabo de probar bien y sí tenia un error. Simplemente si eliminas las `@` funciona ya que estas en un bloque de instrucciones. Mira la repuesta actualizada.